# How to construct Hermitian matrix for minimum, maximum test?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm struggling with understanding of construction of Hermitian matrix from which it is possible to define whether given point is minimum, maximum, or saddle point.

$x^T*A*x$ - this matrix A is the one that I'm talking about.

It is constructed with double partial derivatives; during calculating these values there may appear coefficients with which it will not be possible to make initial function from this formula $x^T*A*x$

My example:
$(,)= 3^3+^2+4−+2$

Hermitian matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}18x & 4 \\ 4 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

However, if I multiply $x^T*A*x$ then result does not correspond to original function.  What is it wrong that I do?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix you call Hermitian is actually the Hessian matrix, the matrix of 2nd partial derivatives of $f$, and is more to do with multi-dimensional calculus than linear algebra.

If that Hessian is positive definite then the stationary point is a local minimizer.
If that Hessian is negative definite then the stationary point is a local maximizer.
(The final case is a saddle point where the Hessian is neither positive not negative definite.)

The value of $x^TAx$ is used to define what is positive or negative definite which will involve it's values for all $x$.

You can also use the determinant of the Hessian to determine the nature of the stationary points in most cases.

A little internet search for key words (Hessian, 2nd derivative test ) will yield a great deal of further information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've searched for it. So, it is not really important for Hessian matrix to be made that way that function could be found through multiplication of $x^T*A*x$?

Comment: @S.Drumble3 To determine the nature of the stationary points you will only need the 2nd partial derivatives evaluated at the stationary points. (The 2nd partial derivatives can also be used in approximating $f$ but then you are probably thinking about Taylor series.)